# Add cell background colors to org-mode table in pdf export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, pdf

I'd like to be able to select a specific cell in an org-mode table and add a background color to that cell for a pdf export. Such that

```
| This Cell is formatted normally | This cell is greyed a bit|
| This cell is greyed as well     | This cell is white again |
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50349/color-only-a-cell-of-a-table), the following works. You must install the xcolor package as instructed there.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[table]{xcolor}

* table test

| hi   | there                              |
|------+------------------------------------|
| this | @@latex:\cellcolor{blue!25}@@ that |
| one  | two                                |
```

Comment: This in fact works for me without the need for `@@latex: ... @@` Simply adding \cellcolor{blue!25} to the cells results in colored cells in the export. Excellent

Comment: Instead of using  \usepackage[table]{xcolor},   \usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} solves the background issue for me in org mode 9.3.7